# Powershell Multiple -Like

Tags: powershell

Afternoon all,

I've got a chunk of Powershell that does something along the lines of:

```
if (($env:COMPUTERNAME -like "AAA*") -or ($env:COMPUTERNAME -like "DAA*") -or ($env:COMPUTERNAME -like "JJD*")) {
   #<Snip> (Do STuff)
}
else {
   #<snip> (Do some other stuff)
}
```

Because I have multiple machine types (prefixed with multiple varying length codes) - I am potentially looking at having a 10-15 item "or" list for the initial if statement.

Is there a cleaner way of doing this or is the above snippet the cleanest way?

This will be run on PS v4 on 8.1/2012R2 kit only - so requirement for a solution to be backward compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put all your prefixes in to an array and reverse the functionality

```
$myArray = "AAA*","DAA*","JJD*"
$result = $myArray | where {$env:COMPUTERNAME -Like $_}
```

`$result.length` will be zero if no matches.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the switch statement.

```
switch -wildcard ( $Env:COMPUTERNAME ) {
  "AAA*" {
    # do stuff here, or set variable
  }
  "DAA*" {
    # do stuff here, or set variable
  }
  "JJD*" {
    # do stuff here, or set variable
  }
}
```

Get more information by typing this command:

```
help about_Switch
```

Answer (score 1):

if they are all 3 letter codes, why not get the first three characters and setup a switch? You could set some variables and then do work based on those variables after the switch statement.

```
switch ($env:computername.substring(0,3))
{
    'AAA' 
    {  <do stuff> }
    'BBB' 
    {  <do stuff> }
    Default
    { <do stuff> }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately not all 3 letter codes, should have been more specific in my question

Answer (score 1):

Regex based solution as well

```
$prefixes = "AAA","DAA","JJD"
$regex = "^({0})" -f (($prefixes | ForEach-Object{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join "|")
If($env:COMPUTERNAME -match $regex){
    Write-host "Something should be happening"
}
```

Put all the letter prefixes into an array then build a regex string with that array that will look for a `$env:COMPUTERNAME` that starts with either of the matches in the array. Using your example the regex match would look like this

```
^(AAA|DAA|JJD)
```

While not needed with your examples, it is a good measure to ensure no control characters end up in the regex string so we use the static method `[regex]::Escape($_)` to ensure that. For simplicity's sake you could have also done

```
$regex = "^({0})" -f ($prefixes  -join "|")
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic check for mutiply wildcards:

```
    $List | ? { $a = $_; ($Wildcards | ? { $a -like $_ }).Count -gt 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what OP wanted was something like (pseudo code)

```
If ($a -like $b -or $c -or $d -or $e) 
{
 do stuff
}
```